# Intercept 400 response generation when Jersey detects bad xml?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I'm writing a test server that needs to emulate a 3rd party RESTful server, I'm using Jersey to write the test server.

All of the requests are POST with application/xml payloads so I started off with:

```
  @Path("GetUserDetails")
  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public GetUserDetailsResp GetUserDetails(GetUserDetailsReq request) {
    ...
  }
```

Jersey happily returns 400 when the XML is badly formatted (GetUserDetailsReq is a JAXB object), which is not what I need. Rather I need to return 200 and an XML error block.

I can get around the 400 by unmarshaling in the method and using an @Provider/ExceptionMapper class, but that's clunky. Is there anyway to specify to Jersey an alternative to returning the 400 declaratively? Maybe a variant on @Provider/ExceptionMapper?

TIA.

Comment: The answer from Pavel Bucek: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Intercept-400-response-generation-when-Jersey-detects-bad-xml-tt7221572.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pavel Bucek answered this in the mailing list: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Intercept-400-response-generation-when-Jersey-detects-bad-xml-tt7221572.html